# Select Row for every 15 minutes in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
 DataType 

      SamplingTime  : Datetime
      Value         : Integer



  SamplingTime          Value
2020-06-08 00:03:58.000 ,  1.00
2020-06-08 00:03:59.000 ,  5.00
2020-06-08 00:02:00.000 ,  3.00
2020-06-08 00:01:58.000 ,  1.00
2020-06-08 00:01:44.000 ,  6.00
2020-06-08 00:01:20.000 ,  2.00
```

**I want Output to get ROW in interval of  15 minutes filter in data should give**

Sample Output

```
2020-06-08 00:03:58.000 ,  1.00
2020-06-08 00:02:00.000 ,  3.00
2020-06-08 00:01:44.000 ,  6.00
2020-06-08 00:01:20.000 ,  2.00
```

**Query which i tried for it :**

```
select dateadd(MINUTE,datediff(MINUTE,-15,SamplingTime),15), value 
from RN_QOS_DATA_0001
```

This rowset contain info for dataSet:

[image: This rowset contain info for dataSet]

Comment: Please, post your test data as text, explain your issue, ask a question and show your attempts.

Comment: Please remove irrelevant tags. Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? these are 2 different systems.

Comment: What's the question? How to group the data into 15-minute intervals? And calculate what? Count? What is the table schema, column types? Some of the tricks possible with `datetime`don't work with `datetime2`

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts I added both tags, as i wanted to know generic quiery which can run on both servers.

Comment: @samrao it's not and it won't. Date arithmetic isn't standardized. Few SQL functions are part of the standard too. You still haven't posted the table schema. MySQL is one of the worst offenders when it comes to SQL compliance, with many common features added only in MySQL 8

Comment: You still haven't explained what you're trying to do. If you want to group the data, you need a GROUP BY clause. It looks like you want the *first* row per 15-min interval though This means filtering and a WHERE clause

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Sorry for delay, I am new to Stackoverflow, i have updated my question. I want to fetch row's in interval of 15 minutes, i have added sample output i want

Comment: This isn't about being new to StackOverflow. How can someone answer if you don't ask what you want? You still haven't said what you want. What is this output supposed to show? I can guess, but perhaps the guess is wrong. `I want Output to get ROW in interval of 15 minutes filter in data` doesn't explain anything - *which* row?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Do i need to add something more? I have added sample output

Comment: Imagine someone asking you that question. Would you be able to answer? Which row do you want? First, last, middle?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the earliest row within each fifteen-minute division of the clock?

```
with data as (
    select *,
        row_number() over (partition by dateadd(second, -1 * (
                               /* how many seconds into 15-minute window */
                               60 * datepart(minute, SamplingTime) % 15
                                  + datepart(second, SamplingTime)
                               ), SamplingTime)
                           order by SamplingTime
        ) as rn
    from T
)
select * from data where rn = 1;
```